# Публикация MVC-приложения на сервер

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, облако

В качестве курсовой писал MVC веб-приложение (связка ангуляра и спринга). Теперь задача стоит организовать виртуальный хостинг где-нибудь в облаке, чтобы приложение испробовать не только на локальной машине.

Как все это грамотно сделать?

Comment: Покупаете хостинг, копируете файлы на сервер - зачем для такого примитива туториалы то?

Comment: Можете взять в аренду какой-нибудь VPS сервер и творите на нем что хотите)

Comment: Легче сказать, чем сделать. Дьявол, как всегда, кроется в деталях. Поэтому ищу какой-нибудь грамотный пример, чтобы не собирать по ходу все грабли.

Comment: 1 Самый легкий способ https://developers.openshift.com/ : Зарегистрируйтесь на RedHat. Скачайте Jboss dev studio закиньте туда проект. Нажимаете правой кнопкой на проект и выбираете publish, вместо сервера в нем выбираете  openshift, студия сама зальет на сервер проект, без танцев с бубном.
На openshift можете разместить бесплатно 3 проекта.

2 Потруднее - бесплатный хостинг на https://www.heroku.com/ там танцы с бубном через git но благо есть пошаговая инструкция

3 Вариант есть еще гугловская платформа, но ничего не могу сказать о ней так как не пробовал сам

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok Спасибо за совет!

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 4):

1. Самый легкий способ developers.openshift.com : Зарегистрируйтесь на RedHat. Скачайте Jboss dev studio закиньте туда проект. Нажимаете правой кнопкой на проект и выбираете publish, вместо локального сервера в нем выбираете openshift(понадобиться вбить логин и пароль), дальше студия сама зальет на сервер проект, без танцев с бубном. Домен будет выглядеть так: "название проекта" - "Ваш ник".rhcloud.com На openshift можете разместить бесплатно 3 проекта. Из DB можно подключить: MongoDB, MySql, PostgreSql.
2. Потруднее - бесплатный хостинг на heroku.com там танцы с бубном через git но благо есть пошаговая инструкция
3. Вариант есть еще гугловская платформа  console.developers.google.com, но ничего не могу сказать о ней так как не пробовал сам, но она тоже богата туториалами